# Django reverse url with optional arguments in template

Tags: python, django, django-urls

In my django project I have a simple url

```
url(r'^report/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.Report.as_view(), name='report')
```

I have placed this particular url at the bottom of my url file for the app. The slug field is an optional argument which may or may not be supplied as part of request.

Now, in a template when I refer to this url with this syntax `{% url 'appname:report' %}` I get an NoReverseMatch found error. I have tried same thing in another app and it works fine. Can anyone point out the probable cause for such behavior? I know I can have two separate urls but if it can be done using one, I would prefer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error becayse `slug` is a required group in your regex.

```
r'^report/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$
```

I believe that you can make it work by wrapping `slug` in a non capturing group and making it optional.

```
r'^report/(?:(?P<slug>[\w-]+)?)/$
```

Personally, I find it clearer to have two entries in urls.py.

```
url(r'^report/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.Report.as_view(), name='report')
url(r'^report/$', views.Report.as_view(), name='report')
```

Comment: Got your point, thanks. I would go with your second suggestion, seems clearer and better in long run. Thank you.

Comment: And the other advantage of the 2 urls is that it forces you to remember that the view needs to operative without a slug

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mention the app name.
Named urls are used to differ urls among different apps.
Try

```
{% url 'report' %}
```

Comment: What if there are two urls with same name across different apps? I guess it won't work. Plus, using app name makes it readable as to which apps url I am referring to.

Comment: you can't use same name for two urls across different apps

Comment: You can. Thats where app name comes in as differentiator.

Comment: I can have two apps A and B, in A's urls i can have url named dashboard also same in B. All I have to do while referring to dashboard in A is `{% url 'A:dashboard' %}`

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar: thanks for pointing out, i just went through the docs and you are right